# How to run the request multiple times and save the response to a single file in SOAPUI?

Tags: request, response, soapui

I'm developing an app in c# to communicate with SOAPUI.
I have a specific Test Case which called TERMEKADAT TestCase, I need to call this TestCase more time than 1 and save the data to file(all responses data to ONE file).
In the c# app I can call the test case using command line and I can storage the response, but i can do it one time(if i do this more times, the dump file will overwritten, so the latest datas are gone).
Can i somehow storage all requests data in ONE file?
Can SOAPUI append the responses in one file?

I need to storage more responses in one file.

Comment: You can add a Groovy test step that appends the reresponse XML to a single file every time it is executed.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Can you help me a little bit how can i do this? I'm new to Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this in a Groovy Script Test Step in your test case:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

def resp = new XmlHolder(context.response) //get the response object
def respXml = resp.getXml()                //get the XML string from the response

def respFile = new File("/your/dir/yourFile.txt")
respFile.append(respXml)
```